# Mixed effects model with data for whole population

Tags: mixed-model, sample, population

I have a dataset about the whole population of interest, not just a sample of it.
I ran a mixed effect model where age and sex are fixed effects; urban area where individuals live and country of origin are random effects; vaccination status is the outcome variable. I intend to explore the association between the independent variables and the outcome variable.
Do I need to consider urban area and country of origin as random effects or, given that I have data for the whole population, does it make sense to treat them as fixed effects, just as I treat age and sex?